# core data issue when saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, restkit

I've been dealing with this issue for almost a week. I am using a framework called restkit and I've been trying to debug it by going through the code in RestKit. The place where it stops executing further is when I am trying to save to a NSManagedObjectContext. I am attaching a sample test project that can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/therekz/Messy). Basically to reproduce the error you have to do the following:

1. Run the app for the first time until the data on the table view loads
2. Stop the app
3. Run the app for the second time, then you'll see a never ending loading spinner

This is basically stuck when it tries to save to the managed object context, which is located on the RKManagedObjectStore.m, the method save (I did put a breakpoint there). I've tried to make sure that everything works, starting from the model, etc... but I don't know what's really going on in here. Can someone please help? The test project that I put a hyperlink above is very simple...

Comment: The `Test.xcdatamodeld` is corrupt as it has no `element` or `layout` files within it.

Comment: Do you really expect people to download several mb of files, build a project and then wade through thousands of lines of code to find your problem? The least you could do would be to post the code where the hang occurs.

Comment: I've pushed my code example so now it's at github

Comment: You have to narrow the problem down to a small enough piece of code that you can post here on SO. Expecting people to go offsite and download code, however that is done, is not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very odd issue. I would take a look at the DBDiscussionBoardExample included with RestKit, and maybe start over. It looks like there's an infinite loop somewhere in RestKit's interface with Three20.

I also find it odd that your server will not respond with json unless the path includes ".json", even if the header asks for json.

You'll save yourself a lot of headache if you use RestKit without Three20. Unless your app needs Three20 for some reason, I find that it just convolutes the code. RestKit has a very clean interface for accessing CoreData as it is.

That said, you can file this as a bug at RestKit's github repo if you like.

And I had to manually add Three20 to your project to get it to load. After looking at your project I see why you couldn't really point to a single spot that was causing a problem, but you should try to make it easier for people who want to help - consider including dependencies with your project, or setup a git repo with submodules.

Comment: Evan, appreciate for the reply.. I've stared at the DBDiscussionBoardExample for a day yesterday and can't seem to find the issue as well. I've asked Blake to look at this issue and yet he finds it weird as well. I would actually want to revert back to my project before three20, but I have spent a great amount of time porting my project with three20 to. Taking this as a lesson and never using three20 again.

Comment: You might check out nimbus in the future: https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus . It's meant to be a feature-for-feature replacement for Three20 which does away with the spaghetti dependencies and lack of documentation and testing. It's also written by the person who took over Three20 from Joe Hewitt. It's not really ready for production yet but it's something to keep your eye on.

Comment: I've actually kept an eye on Nimbus for a while.. too bad RestKit hasn't use nimbus yet

Answer (score 0):

The project you link to does not build out of the box.

Have you tried printing the `NSError` instance from a failed save. Core Data is really good with explaining the errors it encounters. Almost too good, because you will probably have many sub-errors in that error to skim through.

Comment: it needs three20 at your library, so you need to download one.. and I can't print the error as before it finishes saving.. it just loads on and on

Comment: in other words after I call save to the NSManagedObjectContext it just won't execute the next line in the code... it's like an infinite loop hanging in there